# Where does source code for JavaScript itself live?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5, ecma

I don’t know if this is a silly question. But if I want to see and even contribute to JavaScript itself where would I go? I briefly came across https://github.com/tc39 but not sure if this is the right place.

I want to actually see the implementation of maybe something like .toString() to see the code behind it all.

Comment: Different browsers have different JavaScript engines. Chrome has V8, Safari has Nitro etc,.

Comment: So, it is not possible to actually see the implementation of JavaScript within that engine.. and is that open source?

Comment: Some implementations are open source. In particular Chromium and Firefox. Somebody familiar with those should be able to point you in the right direction (which I believe the answer you got is already doing). However, the point of @Spectric is that there isn't a single place, there are multiple. And yes, some are closed. Reason being that the specification is open for anybody to implement, even in closed source software.

Comment: Modern JavaScript runtime systems are **extremely** complicated, working on one of them would require a fairly high degree of experience in modern JIT systems and other optimization techniques.

Answer (score 6):

The official specification lives [here](https://tc39.es/ecma262/). While it's not source code exactly, it thoroughly describes all logic that a JavaScript engine should implement.

There is no *one place* for the actual code that runs JavaScript on machines because there are many different JavaScript engines.

There's V8, which Chrome-related browsers (and modern Edge) run on. Its source can be found [here](https://github.com/v8/v8).

There's [Spidermonkey](https://spidermonkey.dev/), which Firefox runs on.

There's [WebKit](https://webkit.org/getting-the-code/) that Mac apps run on, which is built in the JavaScriptCore JS engine. And there are more.

If you want to "contribute to JavaScript itself", contributing to the [specification proposals](https://github.com/tc39/ecma262) is the way to go - once something is in the spec, it's up to the various JavaScript engines to implement it (which their various maintainers are happy to do, even though it sometimes doesn't occur in a timely fashion).

If you contribute to the development of one of the engines, you'll be improving that engine, but not the entire worldly JavaScript environment.

Comment: WebKit is the graphical engine (which Blink got forked from). The JS engine in Webkit base browsers is [JavaScriptCore](https://trac.webkit.org/wiki/JavaScriptCore)

Comment: Also, "If you contribute to the development of one of the engines, you'll be improving that engine, but not the entire worldly JavaScript environment.", actually most improvements made by one engine are then moved to the specs and benefit the whole ecosystem. It not a single-direction development.